Can I ask this question on Music Fans?
Preface
I recently came across a curious case, which I cannot forget about, so I'm looking for a place where I might find an answer. At its core however, it is about identifying an artist, and I just learned that such questions are unfortunately no longer allowed on Music Fans. But the question also has at least two more layers of relevance to it.
For one, the question is also about potential identity theft, with people pretending to be the artist on several popular streaming platforms. So in that regard, it might also be interesting to the actual artists, who might not be aware of this. Secondly, in a meta kind of way, it's about the failure of music ID services like Shazam to identify the true artist, because they link to the potential pretender. This might therefore also be generally interesting to know to other people.
So in this case, the only way to ID the artist may be to find somebody who knows the true artist. And other than the subreddit r/NameThatSong (where I already asked to no avail), Music Fans seemed to have been the only place to ask about this.
But because of Music Fans' ID policies, I thought I'd ask here first:
The Question
There is this pretty famous video on YouTube of people dancing to a cover of the song Honky Tonk Women by the Rolling Stones. But despite the video's famousness, it's increadibly difficult to find the artist of the song.
According to YouTube, the supposed artist is "CatCalmer", and if you klick on the auto-generated link in the description, you get to this video. But I'm pretty sure there is no artist by the name of CatCalmer since I couldn't find anything about them on the internet (except the video). The CatCalmer video is also obviously an audio rip-off from the dace recording. You can for example hear people cheering in the background, and there is a small audio defect around the 2:05 mark where the audio briefly breaks.
Now curiously, on the cover art that is also automatically linked by YouTube, it claims that the actual artist is "Miesha" and the song is called "Stepper":

If you look for this artist, you actually find this song on Spotify, Amazon Music, and several other platforms. But this is just another audio rip-off from the dance recording, and any other songs by Miesha are also completely different. It is also the version you will find if you for example try to look for the song using Shazam.
So it seems impossible to find the original cover artist without actually knowing who they are. Since the dance recording is quite old, and one of the dancers apparently died in 2009, this cover version must be at least around 15-16 years old. I already listened through many, many other cover versions on Spotify trying to find it, but no luck.
The only other explanation that I currently have is that the cover version was actually a live recording by a small band that never cared to make their music publicly available.
But in any case, I'm fairly certain that neither Miesha nor CatCalmer are the original cover artists of this song.

Identification questions are nowadays off-topic, so this question would get closed.
